# How to delete input files after successful mapreduce

Tags: hadoop, delete-file, recordreader

We have a system that receives archives on a specified directory and on a regular basis it launches a mapreduce job that opens the archives and processes the files within them. To avoid re-processing the same archives the next time, we're hooked into the close() method on our RecordReader to have it deleted after the last entry is read.

The problem with this approach (we think) is that if a particular mapping fails, the next mapper that makes another attempt at it finds that the original file has been deleted by the record reader from the first one and it bombs out.  We think the way to go is to hold off until all the mapping and reducing is complete and then delete the input archives.

Is this the best way to do this?

If so, how can we obtain a listing of all the input files found by the system from the main program?  (we can't just scrub the whole input dir, new files may be present)

i.e.:

```
   . . .

   job.waitForCompletion(true);

   (we're done, delete input files, how?)

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you should define what is a input file. There are several ways to pass a input path to the Mapper. What's more, what is a input path often is determined by the InputFormat you are using. We can also read files by HDFS apis in a Mapper. Is it a input file?

Comment: We've evaluated a number of the suggestions mentioned here but the one that seems to have the most promise involves the creation of a historical PathFilter that writes out all the paths it accepts to a file. The next time it runs it opens the previous file(s) and checks the new candidates for inclusion in the set...and then writes out another history file.  More performant than timestamp lookups since no calls are made to the FileSystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the situation you are explaining I can suggest the following solution:-
1.The process of data monitoring I.e monitoring the directory into which the archives are landing should be done by a separate process. That separate process can use some metadata table like in mysql to put status entries based on monitoring the directories. The metadata entries can also check for duplicacy.
2. Now based on the metadata entry a separate process can handle the map reduce job triggering part. Some status could be checked in metadata for triggering the jobs.

Comment: While that is certainly feasible, the addition of additional processes and tables that need to be maintained makes for more effort that the ones mentioned above. Thanks for your input though!

Answer (score 2):

Couple comments.

1. I think this design is heartache-prone.  What happens when you discover that someone deployed a messed up algorithm to your MR cluster and you have to backfill a month's worth of archives? They're gone now. What happens when processing takes longer than expected and a new job needs to start before the old one is completely done? Too many files are present and some get reprocessed.  What about when the job starts while an archive is still in flight?  Etc.
2. One way out of this trap is to have the archives go to a rotating location based on time, and either purge the records yourself or (in the case of something like S3) establish a retention policy that allows a certain window for operations.  Also whatever the back end map reduce processing is doing could be idempotent: processing the same record twice should not be any different than processing it once.  Something tells me that if you're reducing your dataset, that property will be difficult to guarantee.
3. At the very least you could rename the files you processed instead of deleting them right away and use a glob expression to define your input that does not include the renamed files. There are still race conditions as I mentioned above.
4. You could use a queue such as Amazon SQS to record the delivery of an archive, and your InputFormat could pull these entries rather than listing the archive folder when determining the input splits.  But reprocessing or backfilling becomes problematic without additional infrastructure.
5. All that being said, the list of splits is generated by the InputFormat.  Write a decorator around that and you can stash the split list wherever you want for use by the master after the job is done.

Comment: #3 is the easiest but if we use a store like S3 then a rename is a actually a non-trivial copy-to-new-name which slows things down.  I had a variant of #5 in mind originally but I prefer #2 and am hoping to implement something like it soon.  Thanks so much for your insights.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would probably be do a multiple input job, read the directory for the files before you run the job and pass those instead of a directory to the job (then delete the files in the list after the job is done).

Comment: This was actually the easiest to evaluate but unfortunately with over 200K input files in our scenario the master spent over an hour just calling the MultipleInputs.add(xx) method, not a cheap method to call. It isn't threadsafe either so you can't split the effort.  Thanks for the tip all the same.

Comment: you didn't say you have 200K input files :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use [Apache Oozie](http://oozie.apache.org/) to manage your workflow. From Oozie's website (bolding is mine):

> Oozie is a workflow scheduler system to manage Apache Hadoop jobs.
>
> ...
>
> Oozie Coordinator jobs are recurrent Oozie Workflow jobs triggered by time (frequency) and **data availabilty**.